# Using API to auto send emails created outside Marketo

Tags: email, marketo

I want to create a bi-wekly digest email from various content. I have already created a scraper that will scrape relevant content from across the web and create a beautiful html email. This is all done outside Marketo application.

Now, is there a way or API available in marketo that I can use to auto-send this bi-weekly email outside Marketo application?

There is a create email API http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/asset-api/create-email/ but not sure how this works.

Any kind of direction will be highly appreciated.